# how exactly the compiler will come to know that unknown class will exist before it encounters that class?

Tags: c#

I tried to declare all the classes after the class in which the main class exists.. compiler is not showing the error? how come? see the example below

```
class Program    
{    
public static void Main(string args[])    
{    
A a =new A();    
}    
}    
class A    
{    
//this is class A    
}
```

Comment: when the compiler encounters "A a=new A();" how come it will know that A is a class inside that program?

Comment: if i am correct then the compilation will starts from the start of the file

Comment: [You can use the EDIT link above to include more information to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28758142/edit)

Comment: Simply put, that is how C# works.   It can read entire projects before determining which classes are unknown and figuring out which classes work. (Unlike C and C++, which require strict prototyping)

Answer (score 2):

Because the compiler will parse the entire file to discover the definition of all types before it tries to check for the validity of the identifiers. Hence you can have forward references.

This is not the case for all languages, C requires that every identifier be defined at the point it is used. Thus allowing the compiler to generate code as it goes along. With much less memory on machines in the past this allowed it to compile large code bases with a minimum of resources. Modern machines have plenty of memory and so can cache more information.